# Derivative of a cdf with respect to a parameter

Tags: pr.probability

Given two independent Random Variables $X$ and $Y$ with known distributions, I would like to know if I can say that the expression 
$$
\operatorname{Pr}( f (t'+Y-X)+Y-X < z)
$$ 
is increasing in the parameter $t'$. 
$f(\ )$ is an increasing function

Thanks
L

Comment: The question is about the single random variable $Z=Y-X$, so the independence of $X$ and $Y$ is irrelevant. If $g(x)=f(x)+1$ then $g$ is increasing and you are just asking if Pr$(g(Z+t)<z)$ is increasing in $t$. Actually it is decreasing.

Comment: Sorry the right expression was

Pr( f (t'+Y+X)+Y-X < z)

I cannot express everything as a function of a single R.V. Z as it appear Y+X and Y-X

Comment: If $a\le b$ then the event $f(b+Y+X)+Y-Z\lt z$ is a subset of the event $f(a+Y+X)+Y-Z\lt z$ so the former has the least probability.